# How should I share data between CLI commands in Python?

Tags: python

I want to make a CLI application in Python, but I find that I can't share data between commands. The global variable can't help.

As a example, I get some videos by "xxx search", and I want to press "xxx download 1" to download the frist listed videos, but the data just miss.

I have tried saving data to a file by pickle, and when I run another command, I will read the file and get back the data. But I'm doubting that is that a correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is perfectly valid, you can even use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) to store the file in a clean manner.

Another option is to make a shell within the application, so the it won't exit after every user prompt and create an interface like somewhat like this:

```
$ xxx

>>> search
###
### Your output here
###
>>> download 1
### Done

$
```